# There is a way to optimize this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select cod_curso, anio, id_profesor
from dictado
where (cod_curso, anio) in 
(
    select cod_curso, anio
    from dictado
    where id_profesor in 
        (
            select id_profesor
            from instructor
            where apellido like 'Milmore'
        )  
)
and (id_profesor) not in 
    (
        select id_profesor
        from instructor
        where apellido like 'Milmore'
    )
```

Diagram :

```
    https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/759558366887411773/914258487666692207/unknown.png
```

Task: Write a query to show the last name, first name and date of birth of any instructor who has taught the same courses as "Milmore". Exclude Milmore from the result.

Comment: Your code is in Spanish.  maybe try here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: The correct answer will use `EXISTS()` [and you wont need `NOT EXISTS()` ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will work. However, if you want to write more terse SQL you could denormalize your data model. That is, repeat data to make it easier to get the data you need. Denormalizing data is common in analytics applications to make it easier for reporting.  For example, you could create a new table to relate course with instructor with the following columns.

```
new table instructordictado
cod_curso
nombre_instructor
apellido_instructor
```

and then use the following query.

```
select id_profesor from dictado where cod_curso in 
(select cod_curso from instructordictado where apellido_instructor ='Milmore')
and id_profesor not in (select id_profesor from instructor 
where apellido='Milmore')
```